# How do I access locally connected iPhone from VNC Mac session

Tags: iphone, vnc

I have managed to connect to my Mac Mini from my Windows 7 via TightVNC. I would like to create an iPhone app using XCode and deploy it to the iPhone connected to the windows machine I am VNCing from. Is this possible. Basically I want to do iPhone development using my Windows7 laptop.

TIA
rams

Answer (score 1):

This topic has been discussed many times on StackOverflow:

The biggest issue with TightVNC and Windows <-> Mac is cutting and pasting

Have a look here:

- [What is the best client from Windows to Mac for VNC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117325/what-is-the-best-client-from-windows-to-mac-for-vnc)
- [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

Comment: Thanks. I have reviewed the above posts. I just want the Mac Mini I am VNCing into to see my iPhone connected to my windows 7 laptop. I want the Mac Mini to see the iPhone like you can let windows machines see local drive/disk/usb drives when using RDP.